How to create a custom transform operator?
I'm starting to learn the gears of Scripting and I'm trying to do something quite simple but that seem to end up way more complex than expected for the add-on I'm writing.
I want my add-on to add a Transform Modal shortcut: You would press SPACEBAR to move your current selection in the 3D View, then if you press SPACEBAR again it will constrain the move only to the Y axis.
I can make this behavior easily by adding the shortcut myself in the keymap but I cannot find any solutiong to do that via scripting.
One other post is saying we cannot edit modal keymap via add-on right now. The best would be to re-create a similar operator in order to do what we need from it. In my case, the Transform operator.
How would you proceed from there?
Here is my attempt, the operator is called when pressing SPACEBAR once:
class HP_TranslateModalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
bl_idname = "object.modal_translate"
bl_label = "Modal Translate"
bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

is_moving: bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=False)
constrain_y: bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=False)

def modal(self, context, event):
    if event.type == 'SPACE' and event.value == 'PRESS':
        self.constrain_y = not self.constrain_y     
        bpy.ops.transform.translate(
            'INVOKE_DEFAULT',
            constraint_axis=(False, self.constrain_y, False)  # X, Y, Z constraints
        )
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    if event.type in {'LEFTMOUSE', 'RET'}:  # Confirm operation
        self.is_moving = False
        return {'FINISHED'}

    elif event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:  # Cancel operation
        self.is_moving = False
        bpy.ops.ed.undo()  # Undo the transform
        return {'CANCELLED'}

    return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

def invoke(self, context, event):
    self.is_moving = True
    self.constrain_y = False  # Default: no constraint
    bpy.ops.transform.translate('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
    context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
    return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

Of course the behavior is really not what is expected but I'm not sure I understand what I'm doing wrong.
Thank you for your help!
